# Unable to search directory subtree with WQL query

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, wmi-query, wql, cim

I am attempting to find all .PST files for the logged on user. However, I seem unable to add a path to 'Drive'. I would like to search all files under C:\users\ + $env:UserName

This command seems to find all PST files on C:\

```
$Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -filter "Drive='c:' AND extension='pst'" -OutVariable m | Select-Object -Property Name
```

However when I change this to:

```
$Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -filter "Drive='C:\users\' + $env:UserName AND extension='pst'" -OutVariable m | Select-Object -Property Name
```

or even just:

```
$Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -filter "Drive='C:\users\' AND extension='pst'" -OutVariable m | Select-Object -Property Name
```

I get the following error:

> Get-CimInstance : Invalid query 
>   At C:\Users\mntle2\Documents\PSTMig.ps1:2 char:8
>   + $Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -filter "Drive='c:\users\' AND ex ...
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041017,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

Can somebody please assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: I've looked into this some more: CIM inefficient for _subtree_ searches, so a `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` solution is preferable. Additionally, the CIM method is _broken_ on at least one Windows 10 build from the `1703` update channel.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- In order to perform a **CIM-based** file **search in a directory *subtree*** (as opposed to a single directory), you must **compare the `Path` property with a *drive-relative* path *wildcard* expression using the `LIKE` operator.**

  ```
  "Drive='C:' AND Extension='pst' AND Path LIKE '\\Users\\$env:USERNAME\\%'"
  ```

  - However **this is INEFFICIENT AND SLOW**, because this kind of operation still searches ALL files.

    - By contrast, looking for files in a *single* directory (and not also its subdirectories) works efficiently; e.g.:
      `"Drive='C:' AND Extension='pst' AND Path='\\Users\\$env:USERNAME\\'"`
      would search efficiently in the user's home directory, but only *directly* in it (note the required trailing `\\`)
  - Additionally, this **functionality was temporarily *broken* in some  versions of Windows 10** (observed on at least one build in the `1703` servicing channel).
- Thus, **in order to efficiently locate files anywhere in a directory's *subtree*, use `Get-ChildItem` instead** (with `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` for remoting, if needed) - see below.

---

#### Preferable, much faster alternative based on `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$res = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $HOME -File -Filter *.pst -OutVariable m).FullName
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking `Select-Object -Property Name` in your original command doesn't return the full file paths directly, the way the above command does, but wraps them in custom objects whose `.Name` property contains them.</sup>

In order to run this command on *remote machines*, pass it to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` (from an *elevated* session, with [PS remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq) set up):

```
$res = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $targetComputer { 
         (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $HOME -File -Filter *.pst -OutVariable m).FullName 
       }
```

---

#### Suboptimal CIM solution and general tips for CIM / WMI-based file searches:

Here's the complete solution to the OP's problem, but, as stated:

- it is inefficient and slow
- it is broken on at least one Windows 10 build in the `1703` update channel.

```
$filter = "Drive='C:' AND Extension='pst' AND Path LIKE '\\Users\\$env:USERNAME\\%'"
$Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -Filter $filter -OutVariable m |
  Select-Object -Property Name
```

The `-Filter` argument accepts an [WQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) expression, which can be tricky to construct:

- **`Drive` can only accept a *drive* specification**, so in order to search in  specific *directory* you must use `Path` to target a - drive-relative - *directory path*.

  - Generally, be sure to narrow your search by drive(s), because by default *all* drives are searched, including network drives, which can be very slow.
- The **`Path` argument must have its `\` chars. *doubled* (`\\`)**, because `\` acts as an escape character in string operands.

  - If you use **operator `=`** to specify a path, **only the specified directory *itself* is searched**, which, however, is **efficient**; note that the **path must then end in `\\`**.
  - By contrast, in order to **search the specified path and its *entire subtree*** :

    - *As stated, this is **generally inefficient and slow**, and **broken in some W10 builds**.*
    - use operator `LIKE` instead of `=` and
    - append WQL wildcard character `%` to the path; (in WQL (and SQL, which WQL is based on), `%` is the equivalent of the usual `*` wildcard character,and `_` corresponds to `?`)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the `path` property in your query instead:

```
$Res = Get-CimInstance CIM_DataFile -filter "Drive='C:' AND path='\\users\\' AND extension='pst'" -OutVariable m | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Comment: Does not seem to run as expected. No error is being returned, however no results are returning either... There are certainly files in C:\users so it should be picking them up ? :/

Comment: Are you certain there are files with extension `.pst` under `C:\users`? When you `echo $Res` is there any output?

Comment: `path='\\users\\'` searches only in `\users` directly, not recursively in its subtree.